# Как можно считывать нажата ли клавиша home без while True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, while

Столкнулся с проблемой что надо считывать нажата ли клавиша `home`, но `while True` использовать нельзя поскольку окно `tkinter` перестает работать, Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример взят [отсюда](https://www.codespeedy.com/detect-keypress-in-tkinter-in-python/)

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
root = Tk()

def key_pressed(event):
  w = Label(root,text="Key Pressed:"+event.char)
  w.place(x=70,y=90)

root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: проблема в том что данный метод не считывает такие кнопки как: insert, home, end, pg up, pg dn

Comment: @Selasi там другие ключи вместо <Key>, для ввода насколько помню надо использовать <Return>. Ушел уточнить для home

Comment: @Selasi очень даже считывает, просто нужно не event.char смотреть, а event.keycode или event.keysym

Comment: @Selasi там по ссылке очень неплохо все объяснено

Comment: и как можно исправить то что кнопка считываеться только когда главным окном являеться окно tkinter, просто я планирую сделать так чтоб на кнопку home окно меняло свои размеры на 0x0, и при повторном нажатии обратно

Comment: @Selasi если не ошибаюсь, в этом случае вам надо использовать другую либу, потому что вариант в ответе работает только с виджетами tkinter, а вам похоже надо работать с клавиатурой отдельно - сам не пробовал, но посмотрите вот на эту библиотеку https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

Comment: а можно сделать прозрачное окно tkiner на весь экран которое будет пропускать через себя все нажатия кнопок? И намного ли возрастет задержка при таком методе?

Comment: @Selasi не знаю, не пробовал. Вот так попробуйте `root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)`